# compact framework phone keypad input

Tags: compact-framework, alphanumeric

I am developing an application for a device that has a keypad similar to a phone in which the 2 key is also for ABC, the 3 key is also for DEF, etc.  The expected behavior is similar to a cell phone - if the user presses the 2 key repeatedly it will cycle through 2,A,B,C.  Is there some standard way to do this or pattern for implementing it in .NET (Compact Framework)?  I am sure I'm not the first one to have this requirement.

Edit:  Still no standard solution found...an idea I had was to have a KeypadMgr class that trapped keydown events, started a timer and replaced the 2 character with an A/B/C if it was pressed again within a certain amount of time...any other suggestions?

Comment: +1, I have similar issue, and I didn't found any reliable solution too :/. When you found some solution, I will glad to know them. Thanks.